# I have 2 text files , output text file and input text file , how do I append the lines of input text file at the beginning of output text file(c++)?

Tags: c++

```cpp
file.open(input_file);
char z;
while(file.get(z))
{
    str1 = str1 + z;
    pos1++;
} 
file.close();
fout.open(output_file , ios :: app);
file.seekg(0,ios::beg) ;
fout<<endl;
fout<<str1;
fout.close();

file.open(output_file);
file.seekg(0,ios::beg);

char y;
while(file.get(y))
{
    cout<<y;
}
file.close();
cout<<endl;
```

In the above code, I have used `seekg` and `std::ios::app` function but it adds the input text file at the end of output text file. How do I add it at the beginning?

Comment: `copy output.txt to output.bak`, `copy input.txt to output.txt`, and then `append output.bak to output.txt`.

Comment: Write the input file to the output file ***before*** everything else gets written to the output file?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I get:

```
file.open(input_file);
char z;
while(file.get(z))
{
    str1 = str1 + z;
    pos1++;
} 
file.close();
fout.open(output_file , ios :: app);
char y;
while(file.get(y))
{
    fout<<y;
}
fout<<endl;
fout<<str1;
fout<<endl;
file.close();
```

For some dumb reason, OS's almost never provide means to prepend a file, I suppose thinking to prevent half-empty sectors; so you must re-write it all.  Also, you might want to limit the amount of input, so as to not cause a buffer overflow security risk or memory access crash.  Also, block I/O is much faster.

Comment: The dumb reason: It's inefficient as hell. When you give people an easy way to do something inefficient, they have an annoying tendency to do it and then whine about the poor performance.

Comment: One could have a primitive to write the front; and then when you close it, the rest is appended.  In some cases, it might be faster.  There is vector::push_back() and vector::insert() after all.  Who knows what optimizations might be possible, depending on the buffering and sector structure.

Comment: thank you guys , I got how to do it !!